# CDATA Issue when Filtering by Category using Advanced Profiles

Tags: category, filter, export

Can you somehow indicate exact match within the "Character Data Block"? I'm trying to isolate ONLY products from Category (ID:4) but when I use (4) in the "Character Data Block" for Variable "Filter/Category_ids" (See Below) it returns products for any category (ID) that contains the number 4. For example: 416, 84, 940, 1004, etc. Once again, can exact match be specify in this instance?

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
    <var name="filter/attribute_set"><![CDATA[26]]></var>
    <var name="filter/visibility"><![CDATA[4]]></var>
    <var name="filter/status"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
    <var name="filter/category_ids"><![CDATA[4]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
    <var name="map">
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[SKU]]></map>
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[Product Name]]></map>
        <map name="description"><![CDATA[Description]]></map>
        <map name="url_path"><![CDATA[Product URL]]></map>
        <map name="image"><![CDATA[Image URL]]></map>
        <map name="category_ids"><![CDATA[Category]]></map>
        <map name="special_price"><![CDATA[price]]></map>
        <map name="manufacturer"><![CDATA[Manufacturer]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[sample.csv]]></var>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not implemented this feature but I would like to. Look at this : http://www.excellone.com/blog/magento-developer-notes/adding-new-export-filter-for-products-in-dataflow-profiles-in-magento-version-1-9-3/#.VUN9RaPBzRZ

Relevent section of article here:

> For adding a category filter, the process is comparatively more
>   complex. There will be a change in logic of load() in Adapter.php. For
>   that, a admin module must be created and Adapter.php must be overrided
>   in such a way that it incorporates or uses the category resource model
>   : Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')